# Why is this not a negative half wave rectifier? What is it?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design, rectifier

In the AC circuit below with \$V_{IN} = 20\sin(\omega t)\$ and \$\omega=1\pi\$, we have an ideal diode (inverted) and a capacitor in parallel with a resistor. I want to study the voltage across the resistor.

By studying its behaviour It seems to me that the circuit is a negative half wave-rectifier, but that would be wrong according to the solutions of my textbook. I've drawn the voltage \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$V_{IN}\$ to study the behaviour of the circuit and have simulated it, but it really looks like a negative half-wave rectifier to me.

So why is it not? What is it? And what would be the difference from this circuit to a real negative half wave-rectifier?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBxRK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Input and output voltage waveform]

Comment: It is a negative half wave rectifier.

Comment: Why do you think it is not a negative half wave rectifier?

Comment: It is a negative half-wave rectifier followed by a filter. Is your book being pedantic about that?

Comment: It's an AC source, followed by a negative half wave rectifier, followed by a filter, followed by a load (max pedantry FTW). It will produce a slightly ripply negative voltage out, equal to the peak AC less a diode drop, less a bit of sag while the diode is not conducting.

Comment: Tip: if you use the CircuitLab button **on the editor toolbar** and then, when done, hit the **Save and Insert** button on CircuitLab the editable schematic gets saved in your post. No account. No screengrabs. No image upload. No background grid.

Comment: Please cite  book title and what the text says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your book is being pedantic about, but this *is* a negative half-wave rectifier; you're entirely correct.

You could perhaps argue that only the diode is a half-wave rectifier, and there's other stuff around it. There's a filter, which is often considered part of the rectifier, and a supply and load, which aren't but are usually not mentioned when talking about what a circuit is.

Answer (score 2):

It is a negative-output filtered half-wave rectifier, *or*, equivalently, a negative peak detector.

It is **wrong** to say that it is "not" a half-wave rectifier. It is, functionally speaking, *both* a (filtered) half-wave rectifier **and** a peak detector. These are two names for such circuits, and the name chosen only depends on which function is considered more descriptive when analyzing the circuit.